# Synchronization with OpenMP, For directive

Tags: c, multithreading, synchronization, openmp

I would like to make a little sample code in order to test the Open MP API.
I have made a three level For loop with a calcul in this.

The problem is that my result is wrong.

Here is my code :

```
long value = 0;
#pragma omp parallel
{
#pragma omp for
for (int i=0;i<=9999;i++)
{
    value += (M_PI * i * i -12,33 * M_PI)- M_PI;

    for (int j=0;j<=888;j++)
    {
        value += (M_PI * j * i -12,33 * M_PI)- M_PI;

        for (int k=0;k<=777;k++)
        {
            value += (M_PI * k * j -12,33 * M_PI)- M_PI;    
        }
    }
}
}
```

My problem :

Without Open MP, the value of the `value` variable is : `191773766`
Whit Open MP, the value of the `value` variable is :    `1092397966`

I think that is a synchronization problem, but how to solve this ?
I have read a lot about Open MP, but I don't find how solve it.

Thanks a lot,

Best regards,

Answer (score 7):

You're missing the `reduction(+:value)` clause.

```
#pragma omp parallel reduction(+:value)  //  add reduction here
{
#pragma omp for
```

The reason why you need it is because you are sharing the `value` variable across all threads. So they asynchronously update it leading to a race condition. (You also get a performance hit from cache coherency.)

The `reduction(+:value)` clause tells the compile to create a separate instance of `value` for each thread and then sum them up at the end.

---

**EDIT : Full code at OP's request.**

```
int main() {

    double start = omp_get_wtime();

    long M_PI = 12;

    long value = 0;
#pragma omp parallel reduction(+:value)
{
#pragma omp for
for (int i=0;i<=9999;i++)
{
    value += (M_PI * i * i -12,33 * M_PI)- M_PI;

    for (int j=0;j<=888;j++)
    {
        value += (M_PI * j * i -12,33 * M_PI)- M_PI;

        for (int k=0;k<=777;k++)
        {
            value += (M_PI * k * j -12,33 * M_PI)- M_PI;    
        }
    }
}
}    
    double end = omp_get_wtime();
    printf("\n\nseconds = %f\n",end - start);

    cout << value << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

**Output: (without OpenMP)**

```
seconds = 0.007816
738123776
```

**Output: (with OpenMP - 8 threads)**

```
seconds = 0.012784
738123776
```

If you want any speedup, you need to make the task *much* larger.

Comment: Biggest performance hit when using shared _automatic_ variables comes from the fact that they are accessed through pointers inside the OpenMP parallel region. The latter is extracted into a separate function and provided with a data structure, containing pointers to all shared automatic variables, allocated on the stack of the main thread. Less performance hit comes from cache coherency and NUMA effects.

Comment: The cacheline that holds the shared automatic variables will be bounced back and forth between the cores. So it should still go back to cache coherence. Though I'm not sure what the behavior is for atomic operations using the x86 lock prefix.

Comment: GCC emits 2 `movl` and one `addl` instructions per increment for the serial version or when `value` is a global/static shared variable and 2 `movq`, 6 `movl` and one `addl` instructions per increment when `value` is a shared automatic variable (corresponds to `*(data->value_ptr) += increment_value;`)

Comment: Funny, I get about a 1177x difference between with and without the reduction. Neither the cache coherence nor that extra level of indirection can make that difference. Extra levels of indirection rarely get more than 2 - 10x slower. Whereas coherence cache misses are only the order of 100x for this type of loop. So it's probably a combination of both of them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Mystical, nevertheless the result of value is wrong with "reduction(+:value)" :(. Do you know why ?

Comment: Then it's probably your algorithm that's not correct. With the `reduction(+":value)` I get the same output for any number of threads and between runs. So that solves the data-race problem. But if the number is wrong: I don't know what your code is supposed to do, so I can't help with that.

Comment: my algorithm is just in order to show how OMP is used. The value += (M_PI * k * j -12,33 * M_PI)- M_PI;  is juste a calcul. I just want the same result with and whitout OpenMP.

Comment: I'm getting the same number with and without OpenMP. Using `M_PI = 12`, I get `738123776` both with and without OpenMP.

Comment: Could you please paste me your code ? I would like to understand my error :( Thanks a again :)

Comment: Thanks, with your code, it's ok ! Now, please, replace long M_PI= 12 with double M_PI = 3.14159265358979323846; With this, the result are not indentical

Comment: I still get the same number... `2.65932e+012` both with and without OpenMp.

Comment: And you have just modify the M_PI declaration ? My results are : 191773766 without Open MP and 149249136  with OpenMP :(

Comment: Wait, I messed up my test case. I'm able to reproduce your numbers. I'm suspecting floating-point round-off, but I haven't been able to confirm/deny it. Ask it as a separate question since I don't know the answer to that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. In fact, i use a 3.14159265358979323846 value in order to having a slow execution ;)